# CDSWebApiService not working with MFA enabled

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-automate, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to connect to PowerApps WebApi using CDSWebApiService provided by microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/samples/cdswebapiservice
I have used the sample code that Microsoft provided to connect to Web API of Power Automate and that works fine for the normal users.

But when we turn on the MFA for the user that its giving authentication errors to call API.

Basically I am trying to call WorkFlows API.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/web-api)

Or is there any other way to call Power Automate Web API? Using CRM Service client or something else?

Answer (score 0):

you should use Application user to make API calls, especially when your company has MFA enabled.
With Application user you can have clientID and secret and that can be used.

Also I think application user does not use MFA.